# Copy cells including output from one notebook to another?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

is there a way to copy a cell with code and its output in Google Colab or in jupyter notebooks in general and paste it into another notebook?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the cell by drag selecting or command-clicking. Then, Control-C / Control-V keyboard shortcuts will copy/paste the cell between notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, hold Ctrl button and now with your mouse select all the cells that you want to copy. After selecting, press Ctrl+C to copy and Ctrl+V to paste.

Comment: This question was already answered with the same answer. What did your answer add?

Comment: @C. Fennel They described how it works on Windows